# Having trouble with getJSONObject method

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to populate an adapter with information from my jsonArray. I have seen this done in many examples but I am getting an error that "The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Here's the code...

```
// jsonArray declared and filled with information
int length = jsonArray.length();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        String obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("NAME");
        adapter.add(obj);
    }
```

Comment: WHat is the type of the jsonArray variable?

Comment: JSONObject, that could very well be the problem

Comment: Guess you answered your own question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation, the prototype of the function is not `getJSONObject(int)` but `getJSONObject(java.lang.String)`, so you can't use this function with your i

I think you can use the `keys()` function to get an Iterator with string name.